# Map <C-J> to <Space> in all possible modes

Tags: key-bindings, map-operator

My space bar no longer works unless I lean my weight on it.  The chances of getting the laptop replaced in a timely manner is close no nil.

I mostly use vim or vi, even from the bash command line.  With combinations of the commands below, I've been able to replace `<Space>` with `<C-j>` in `Normal` and `Insert` modes, and even in `Command-Line` mode:

```
nmap <C-J> <Space>
map! <C-J> <Space>
omap <C-J> <Space>
map <C-J> <Space>
lmap <C-J> <Space>
omap <C-J> <Space>
```

I haven't been able to create the mapping in the mode in which I press `f`/`F` to move forward/backward to the character that is typed next.

**What mode would that be?**

**Is there a way to map `<C-J>` to `<Space>` in that mode?**

I would have thought that falls under `Operator-pending` mode, which falls under the `map` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `:h f` you'll see

> |:lmap| mappings apply to {char}

(as in `f{char}`)

Go to `:h mapmode-l`:

```
":lmap" defines a mapping that applies to:
...<snip>...
- the argument of the commands that accept a text character, such as "r" and "f"
```

So `lmap <c-j> <space>` ... note, though, that you may need to explicitly enable `lmap` mappings by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> *while in Insert mode*. Alternatively, ensure that `'iminsert'` is set to 1.

(The docs are misleading about this, btw. What I'm reading is that this setting only applies to use of `lmap` mappings used in Insert mode. But a simple test reveals that it applies to the `f` family of Normal mode commands. Anyone have a different interpretation of `:h 'imi'` and `:h mapmode-l`? Am I insane?)

FYI: you can also solve your problem by brute forcing it with `:nnoremap f<c-j> f<space>` and for `F`,`t`,`T`.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention, I tried that too. Based on the help tables of what commands work in which modes. I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate, pleaes? I am literally using the 7 characters `<Space>` in the `lmap` command. I tried the `lmap` command using literal space character preceded by `Ctrl+^` for the RHS.  Also tried `<C-^><C-J>` as the RHS. Also tried invoking the mapping by typing `<C-^><C-J>` after a `f`/`F` command, but again no joy. Your `nnoremap f<c-j> f<space>` worked.

Comment: I do issue the `lmap` command exactly as you show. In normal mode, I also enter `F<C-^><C-J>`. I get an error "bong" when the <C-^> key is pressed.

Comment: `<c-^>` shouldn't be anywhere near your mapping! Not when you create the mapping and not when you utilize the mapping. You use `<c-^>` one time, alone, in Insert mode, to toggle the functionality. It's a setting. Just like `'iminsert'` is.

Comment: That works great! I tried to google `vim what-are-langauge-characters`, but the returns seem to focus on special characters. Would you know of a good reference that explains this? Thanks.

Comment: You're talking about all this lang map stuff? In addition to the help references in my answer there's also `:h language-mapping`. Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: `Ctrl-^` "toggle[s] the use of typing language characters". It sounds like a weird mode of sorts, in which `lmap` mappings work. Googling `vim what-is-an-input-method` returns a very generic definition, and [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679709/input-method-in-vim). It's not clear whether `lmap` mappings alone constitute an input method, or *can* constitute an input method.

Comment: It's also strange that `omap <C-J> <Space>` doesn't work for me. `:h omap-infp` says `":lmap" defines a mapping that applies to...the argument of the commands that accept a text character, such as "r" and "f"`

Comment: Yeah, the docs are atypically muddled on this topic. But "language characters" in that context, I believe, just means characters entered as text (versus those used to initiate commands). In one state when you hit ctrl-j it moves the cursor (Normal mode command) the other state it goes specified text (the "language character" "space"). Or something...it's too late, I shouldn't be thinking about this anymore. ;)

Comment: Really appreciate the in-depth explanation. Thanks.

Comment: You bet. Glad everything is working. Cheers.

Comment: Even better: They replaced the laptop.  And better still, it's the same model, with the HDD from ye olde laptop swapped in, i.e., no customization or configuration needed, as it comes with along with the HDD.